# Quickly rotate image section in Java

Tags: java, performance, sprite, affinetransform

I would like to rotate, scale, and translate a section of an image. For example, I have a sprite-sheet with columns and rows of sprites. I can draw the section I want onto a temporary BufferedImage, then transform that temporary image onto the main graphics, but this is a very slow operation.

How can I make this much much faster? It needs to occur more than 100 * 60 times per second.

```
public void Draw_WorldSpace(Graphics2D g, double x, double y, double angle, double deltaTime) {
    // setup portion of image to transform
    BufferedImage tempImage = new BufferedImage(sourceRectangle.width, sourceRectangle.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = tempImage.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, sourceRectangle.width, sourceRectangle.height, sourceRectangle.x, sourceRectangle.y, sourceRectangle.width, sourceRectangle.height, null);
    g2.dispose();

    // setup a transformation object
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    // match view rotation
    transform.translate(GameLogic.viewPort.GetCanvasCenter().x, GameLogic.viewPort.GetCanvasCenter().y);
    transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(GameLogic.viewPort.GetAngle()));
    transform.translate(-GameLogic.viewPort.GetCanvasCenter().x, -GameLogic.viewPort.GetCanvasCenter().y);
    // set to position
    transform.translate(x - GameLogic.viewPort.GetViewPortCenter().x + GameLogic.viewPort.GetCanvasCenter().x, y - GameLogic.viewPort.GetViewPortCenter().y + GameLogic.viewPort.GetCanvasCenter().y);
    // rotate
    transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
    // center on sprite
    transform.translate(-sourceRectangle.width / 2, -sourceRectangle.height() / 2);
    // draw the sprite
    g.drawImage(tempImage, transform, null);
}
```

Comment: Do it in advance and store the rotated sprites in a `List<Image>`.

Comment: Could perform the translation directly on the "main" `Graphics` instead of performing it on the sub image?

Comment: What needs to occur more than six kHz?

Comment: @trashgod Probably 100+ sprites onscreen at 60fps

Comment: You might also want to have a look at some of the other [`Graphics#drawImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-int-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) methods which allow you to draw different portions of the image - this may reduce the need for a temporary image

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I did what [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) suggested. I wasn't the biggest fan of the solution simply because it requires a lot of memory overhead. But ultimately, it worked like a charm and even game me more streamlined control over the graphics, so that's really cool.